# Nuclear accident near Uranium mine

Tags: nuclear-physics

What if someone, without knowing, detonates a very small nuclear bomb underground within a rich mine (rich on Uranium but not enriched type) that has ~500 tons scattered to 1km³. Would the neutron density be enough to start a nuclear explosion just before everything evaporates and pushed far? (I think not, but someone not lazy could prove it)

Comment: did you heard about such project ? where ?

Comment: No, I did not hear. I was just watching how many nuclear tests done on youtube then I saw some of the underground ones that inflated the ground. I just wondered if any of those hundreds of tests ever happened near a mine such that they expect x energy yield but suddenly they got 10x yield. Or is there a slightest possibility of not detecting isotopes 1km under surface.

Comment: Congrats, you have just been added to the American terror watch list. Apart from that, this would be a waste of a good uranium mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a bomb is not a simple matter, a lot of isolating the correct isotope with centrifuges is necessary , and it is called [weapons grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapons-grade) ore. Natural deposits do not have weapons grade uranium.

Interestingly enough there are signs that fission of the type happening in fission reactors [has happened once on earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor) naturally:

> Oklo is the only known location for this in the world and consists of 16 sites at which self-sustaining nuclear fission reactions took place approximately 1.7 billion years ago, and ran for a few hundred thousand years, averaging 100 kW of thermal power during that time.

So at worst a bomb close by might start [such a reaction](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ancient-nuclear-reactor/)

> In 1953 George W. Wetherill of the University of California at Los Angeles and Mark G. Inghram of the University of Chicago pointed out that some uranium deposits might have once operated as natural versions of the nuclear fission reactors that were then becoming popular. Shortly thereafter, Paul K. Kuroda, a chemist from the University of Arkansas, calculated what it would take for a uranium ore body spontaneously to undergo selfsustained fission. In this process, a stray neutron causes a uranium 235 nucleus to split, which gives off more neutrons, causing others of these atoms to break apart in a nuclear chain reaction.

A very slow process, as the Oklo mines prove.

Comment: Hypothesis in second link says the moon is originated from a geo-reactor explosion .

Comment: Yep, the Oklo deposit is the answer here.  It could and did happen at least once in the past, but can no longer. Chemistry mixes U-235 and U-238, and the shorter-lived fissionable U-235 has undergone six times as many half-lives as the longer-lived U-238 since earth formed.  The fuel is gone.